# Anything-goes future Olympics where competitors can dope

Tags: story-identification

I'm struggling to remember the details of this, but I'm positive it's not *[Achilles Choice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/850597.Achilles_Choice)*.  I would have read this in the mid 1990s, but I don't even recall if it's a novel or a novelette.

The protagonist is a (mostly?) baseline human in competition at a future Olympics. The primary conceit of the story is that attempts to prevent doping were completely abandoned, and as a result all major countries went into doping in a big way.  I don't know if gene doping was a topic yet, but if it were known it would have been included.

I don't remember what sport the protagonist was competing in, but I think he only took drugs to improve his reaction time or something like that; physically he looked pretty normal.  However, his closest confidant was a weightlifter who weighed something like 600 pounds (obviously a US novel) who was able to lift something crazy like 1300 pounds.  The weightlifter was basically a mountain of muscle who had to eat all the time to keep his metabolism going, and who suffered all kinds of side effects.

The weightlifter is clearest in my mind, but I think the gymnasts (at least the women) were tiny having had their growth prematurely arrested, and other competitors had other kinds of induced abnormalities in addition to their regimen of drugs.

I don't really recall how the story ended, except that the weightlifter dies of a heart attack.

Comment: I have a similar recollection of a short story where the premise is the same (unrestricted doping) but the sport was football. I think it was intended to be humorous or satirical because the "punch line" was that it all became pointless when one team engineered a goal keeper that was the same size as the goal but just mobile enough to be able to get from one end to the other at half time. Perhaps it was a themed anthology of "what if no doping?" stories?

Comment: @adamT - I believe the 'goal-sized goalie' to be a joke from one of the Red dwarf books. If memory serves, Scotland still failed to qualify for the World cup

Comment: Sounds like it could be either "The Mickey Mouse Olympics" or "Glint of Gold" from https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/let-me-root-root-root-for-the-home-team

Comment: Ah, probably not the former, http://www.williamflew.com/omni9a.html

Comment: @Valorum - yes could be. I'm pretty sure I read the anthology that this story was in ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Science_Fictional_Olympics ) as I recognise some of the other synopses, so could well have merged the Red Dwarf joke as part of it in my memory.

Comment: Not related, but SNL did an ALL drugs olympics with Phil Hartman. Worth a look.

Comment: “Omni” magazine its heyday did an article (not a story) about the future of enhancements in sport. Who would go full cyborg-mechanical and who would lean to bio-tech mods. The illustration always has stuck with me: a 2.5-3 meter athlete standing patiently while a team in lab coats cluster around like a pit crew

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be Simon Hawke's "[A Glint of Gold](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49739)" (first published under the pen name of Nicholas Yermakov). It's about genetic manipulation, not drugs. According to [this article](http://historynewsnetwork.org/blog/3082), "Yermakov's story focuses on the human (well, mostly human) costs of single-purpose people", which would match up with your idea that the characters are hyperspecialized. The magazine where it first appeared, [*The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction* for July 1980](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v059n01_1980-07/page/n72/mode/2up) is available on the Internet Archive.

The protagonist, Landry, is a bit more modified, having webbed hands and being streamlined for better swimming:

> Landry draped his hand around the
> dolphin's back, his webbed fingers
> closing around the dorsal fin as George
> pulled him through the water .... Banyon watched as Landry climbed
> up out of the pool, the water streaming
> from his streamlined body.

Landry's friend is Wallford, who is introduced lifting a thousand pounds. And indeed, he's constructed for lifting:

> The short, massive power
> lifter looked like a prize bull. He had
> no neck to speak of, and his shoulders
> were almost as wide as he was tall. His
> arms were at least three times the size
> of Banyon's thighs and his legs were
> like tree stumps. He moved ponderously, his breathing labored. Sweat covered his entire body so that he gleamed in
> the bright lights. His flanks were
> lathered with foam.

And indeed, he's a big eater:

> "I couldn't go," replied the power
> lifter, breathing heavily. Before him,
> the table was crowded with his meal. It
> consisted of forty-seven scrambled
> eggs, six cartons of orange juice, a
> gallon of his special protein drink, five
> Porterhouse steaks, (medium rare), a
> bowl of vegetarian beans, stone-ground wheat bread with peanut butter (an entire loaf), a huge bowl of mixed salad greens and carrots, a smaller
> bowl of radishes, wild rice with
> shrimp, a broiled bluefish, and several
> bottles of food supplements.

Landry is considerably less modified, however, than his Russian opponent, Mikhailov, who has gills.

> He was sleek and
> streamlined and his skin had a flat,
> shark-like sheen. His hands and feet
> were webbed, like his, but they were
> larger and his muscles were long and
> striated. His chest capacity looked
> huge. The most noticeable features
> were, of course, the gills, set in his
> flanks just ahead of his manta-like
> latissimus dorsi muscles. They seemed
> to possess a life of their own as they
> moved with a beautiful, rippling motion.

And indeed, Wallford dies of a heart attack:

> "Yeah, well, you might say that.
> He had a heart attack. Coronary
> thrombosis. I'm afraid he didn't make
> it."

Found with a search for `science fiction olympics genetically modified weightlifter`, which led to the above-mentioned article about how the idea of genetically modified competitors won't be science fiction for long.

Comment: The July 1980 issue of *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* is [available at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v059n01_1980-07/page/n72/mode/1up) if you want to grab some quotes from it.  I think I must have borrowed a friend's copy of *The Science Fictional Olympics* since the first one of that series I have is *Supermen*.

Comment: @DavidW: Thank you. I must not have been searching The Internet Archive properly to find that one.

Comment: It's really hard to search IA for issues of F&SF.  I start from [The Pulp Magazine Archive](https://archive.org/details/pulpmagazinearchive) and do a metadata search for "fantasy science fiction {year}".  It still pulls in extra stuff, but it's only about 20-30 results instead of hundreds or thousands.